# make: xscale_be-gcc: Command not found

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, make, arm

I'm new to embedded and am reading 'Embedded Linux Primer' at the moment.

I tried to build an xscale arm kernel:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=xscale_be- ixp4xx_defconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
```

followed by the make:

```
~/linux-stable$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=xscale_be- zImage
make: xscale_be-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: xscale_be-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

I had downloaded and extracted gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4 from
https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

and set the path

PATH=/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin/

Do I need another compiler for the xscale architecture?

Any ideas where I can find xscale_be-gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading the same book and get stuck in the same part, so... after some research i finally compiled the kernel for ixp4xx target

Download the ARM toolchain from:
[Devloper arm Compiler v6](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/compilers/arm-compiler/downloads/version-6)
then...

> $ mkdir -p ~/opt
>
> $ cd ~/opt
>
> $ tar xjf ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2
>
> $ chmod -R -w ~/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update

look if the installation is correct

> ~/opt$ gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc --version

The output will be something like this:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors 6-2017-q2-update) 6.3.1 20170620 (release) [ARM/embedded-6-branch revision 249437]
> Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc...

Now you can prepare your Kernel source tree

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi- ixp4xx_defconfig

And finally compile...

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi- zImage

[image: Success!]

Maybe it is not the best compiler for the target or need a kernel patch but... in order to follow each step in the book i think is enough.

BR,

Answer (score 1):

What is your board ? Did you configure the Kernel ? You need to configure the Kernel to match your board and specify the corss-compile toolchain.

Isn't the `arm-none-eabi-*` for bare-metal ? Not for linux. Who siad you need to use `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4` ?

Also, you are resetting the PATH! Do this:

PATH=$PATH:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin/