# /bin/sh: xscale_be-gcc: command not found

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compilation

I'm learning how to build a Linux OS image for my embeded project, And I'm reading 'Embedded Linux Primer'.

I tried to compile the kernel for the ARM XScale and got stuck at

> $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=xscale_be- ixp4xx_defconfig

I got these errors:

```
/bin/sh: xscale_be-gcc: command not found
/bin/sh: xscale_be-gcc: command not found
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
/bin/sh: bison: command not found
scripts/Makefile.lib:196: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c] Error 127
Makefile:544: recipe for target 'ixp4xx_defconfig' failed
make: *** [ixp4xx_defconfig] Error 2
```

What did I miss now and how to fix it?

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188943/make-xscale-be-gcc-command-not-found/376134#376134

Comment: Do you have a cross compiling toolchain installed?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i find out.

Firstly, installing arm-none-eabi-gcc following this [install arm cross compiler](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/arm/install/)

Secondly, install bison

> sudo apt-get install bison

Finally, modify the command

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-  ixp4xx_defconfig